# Kubernetes maxPods int32 also include its defaults pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I want to set the maximum allowed pods (that my application need/create) on any kubernetes node as '3' (in Default namespace).

When I set `maxPods: 3` in `/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml`, seems like it also includes the pods cerated by kubernetes internally(`namespace: 'kube-system'`) in this number. In other words unless I set maxPods to 7 (on the node which is also Master) I cannot get any application pod created in default namespace.

My node ( I set `maxPods` on node1.co.com as '8' and I can only get 2 application pods in default namespace):

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o json | jq '.items[] | {name: .metadata.name, cap: .status.capacity}'
{
  "name": "node1.co.com",
  "cap": {
    "cpu": "2",
    "ephemeral-storage": "8649700Ki",
    "hugepages-2Mi": "0",
    "memory": "8007036Ki",
    "pods": "8"
  }
}
{
  "name": "node2.co.com",
  "cap": {
    "cpu": "2",
    "ephemeral-storage": "8649700Ki",
    "hugepages-2Mi": "0",
    "memory": "8009324Ki",
    "pods": "9"
  }
}
```

Any additional pods are in pending state:

```
$ kubectl create -f single-node-deployement4.yaml
$ kubectl get pods -o=wide --all-namespaces | grep Pending

default       single-node-deployment4-585466c56c-sszdz                  0/1     Pending     0          17s     <none>           <none>                                  <none>           <none>
```

$ kubectl get pods -o=wide --all-namespaces | grep OutOf

```
kube-system   coredns-86c58d9df4-7gb5d                                        0/1     OutOfpods   0          7d19h   <none>           node1.co.com   <none>           <none>
kube-system   coredns-86c58d9df4-t6rcj                                        0/1     OutOfpods   0          7d19h   <none>           node1.co.com   <none>           <none>
```

Is number of kubernetes internal pods constant and I can assume to have maximum of three pods, I can set `'maxPods: 9'` or is there a better way to set `maxPods`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve the same result

- limit #Pods per namespace
- do not schedule on master node

by using these Kubernetes policies/features together:

1. [ResourceQuota](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/#object-count-quota) (object count quota)
2. [Node Taint](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/)

Example:

**Create resource quota based on object count:**

- `kubectl create namespace limited`

> `# Source: object-count-quota.yaml
>   apiVersion: v1
>   kind: ResourceQuota
>   metadata:
>     name: object-counts
>   spec:
>     hard:
>       pods: "3"`

- `kubectl create -f ./object-count-quota.yaml -n limited`
- `kubectl describe resourcequota -n limited`

**Make master node unschedulable:**

- `kubectl taint nodes master-node key=value:NoSchedule`

Comment: Yes I saw resourceQuota options which can work for me but in this case I need to add each node in separate namespace and then create one resourceQuota for each node. Please correct me if I am wrong. I am planning to have more then 50-80 nodes in the cluster.

Comment: I'm afraid you are wrong. You can't add node to specific namespace. Nodes are example of low-level resources, and do not live in any namespace. Namespaces are a way to divide cluster resources between multiple users/teams via resource quota = a type of constraints that limit aggregate resource consumption per namespace, not per node. Open Source projects like Deis Workflow (PaaS Platform on top of K8S), that allows different teams to deploy and run their workloads on the same cluster, also needs to tackle this problem somehow, and they do it via resource quota, see tuning-component-settings.md

Comment: Thanks Nepomucen for the comments, but my requirement is for auto scale for my CI/CD server where I need to bound to same POD template(having same namespace) for all the containers requirement. So for this I need to use the same namespace. Also I cannot have more then 3 pods on any node because of resource requirements. That is why maxPods serves my purpose best , but it is not working for me.